# MS Access : Navigation pane is suppressed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I received a MS Access form client. It is in access 2007 format. Initially Navigation Pane was not available. Only form was visible. Then I choose options->Current database->checked Display Navigation Pane check box. It is visible now. But It is suppressed and not able to resize or access it as shown in below screenshot. I checked the code by pressing Alt+F11. I could not find script related to navigation pane. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you press F11 you can open and close the navigation pane. If it is stuck try grabbing the bar and sliding open manually. You do this by putting the cursor on the bar until it turns into a horizontal arrow. Seen here. Once fully open again it should work fine.

[image]